# static referance for firebase database in angular 4 (AngularFire)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Coming here from Android and in my android projects I usuly making a firebaseController that looks something like that:

```
public class FirebaseController {
private static DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

public static Observable<FirebaseChildEvent> observeCity() {
    return observe(dbRef.child(/city));}
}
```

where I can add any Observable I want...
-Main key to it is getting DatabaseReferance as a static value so that I can call it from anywhere without creating new instance of FirebaseController -that said I'm having some issue to make a static value of AngularFireDatabase in Angular 4 beacause instance of angularFireDatabas is passed only trough constructor and trying to make new instance of it using 'new' -keyword doesn't work for me neaither -surly missing some of the basics on this one so some guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject AngularFireDatabase service into your FirebaseController. Then you can make your FirebaseController a service and inject it wherever needed.

Comment: ty- will google up "angular incjection" and hopefully I will figure it out (y):)